# Session not working in Jquery file upload plugin integration, laravel 5

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, jquery-file-upload

I have integrated Jquery file uploader plugin via `https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/`. Its working perfectly. I have placed the `server` folder of the plugin in `/public` of laravel. Now i have to use the session variable to check the maximum file size available for particular user, authenticating user etc. There are two files in `server/php` if you can see. I am trying to use like this, which is not affecting anything. `if (session_id() == '') {
    @session_start();
    /* or Session:start(); */
}
$uid=$_SESSION['id'];
print $uid;`

I also tried the same thing in the userController.php's constructor using `$this->uid=$_SESSION['id'];`  Nothing seems working . I am not understanding how to access sessions in this. Or any other way via which i can try?
Thank You!

Comment: Are you routes under web middleware? You need to post your code at least routes.php and your controller as well that handle the ajax or upload request.

Answer (score 1):

12-05-16-vh
Implimenting Jquery file uploader to laravel

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Download the zipfile from above link
put them in public folder(I have placed in public/asset/vender/)
The server/php is the one where the important codes(**index.php, uploadhandler.php**) where kept.
If use that, the sessions cannot be accessed.

Best way is to make customization to the code
update **main.js** in /js folder of the plugin byChanging this line
  **url: 'server/php/'**
to some controller route
**eg:   url: 'file_uploader'**
then in the routes.php, give connection to a controller class for file_uploader'

```
Route::post('file_uploader', 'userController@file_uploader');
```

Route::get('file_uploader', 'userController@file_uploader');
Route::DELETE('file_uploader', 'userController@file_uploader');

In the userController, create a function, which can then initate the instance of the uploadHandler class(which we are going to place in seperate controller)
add this in beginnig of  userController
use **App\Http\Controllers\UploadHandler;**

and then   have this method which creates instance of  UploadHandler

```
public function file_uploader(Request $request)
{
     $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
}
```

create a controller named  UploadHandler, add all the namespaces and other stuffs,
copy the class  UploadHandler which is there in  UploadHandler.php of the plugin. Now in this UploadHandler class contrsuctor you can call Your sessions(make sure to write **use Session;** in beginning of controller.

For deleting file, 
update $file->deleteUrl object  `public function set_additional_file_properties($file)` and it should look like below now

```
$file->deleteUrl= 'file_uploader?'
        .$this->get_singular_param_name()
        .'='.rawurlencode($file->name);
```

I am posting a gross answer above, You can do some workaround to make it accessible.